# VSTS online storage access after performing a build

Tags: build, storage, azure-devops

I use VSTS to build a project once changes are checked in from a git repository.  That build gets stored in vsts storage.  Now is there any way to easily access any retained build and copy it out for some other purpose? that is, say i've done 5 build versions.. all retained in the history of vsts.  I need a copy of the 2nd build for something.   Can i get to that build folder and copy it?

currently in one of the build steps it gets copied to an area called 
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\xxxxx.zip

how can i get a copy of that?  trying to avoid having to remote into the build agent and dig up the files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Publish Build Artifacts* task. That will upload it as a linked artifact to the build, which you can then download either via clicking on the "Download" link or via the VSTS REST API.